# Crop distorting / scaling image

Tags: php, image, gd, crop, image-resizing

I have the follow PHP code:

```
$w = 300; // Width of new image
$h = 300; // Height of new image
$oh = 540; // Original file height
$ow = 720; // Original file width
$x = 196;
$y = 50;

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('fileToCrop.jpg');
$cropped_image = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($cropped_image, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $ow, $oh, $w, $h);

imagejpeg($cropped_image, 'fileToCrop.jpg', 100);
```

And want to crop the image, but my images are distorting / higher than original, eg:

**Original:**

[image]

**Cropped ("N" for "Not" are showing):**

[image]

I can't see what is wrong with my code, and what are happening to images goes bigger..

Comment: The original dimensions are 720x540. Use the following function to get the height/width. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: @twodayslate Sorry, it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted the last 4 parameters of `imagecopyresampled`

```
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

Change it for

```
imagecopyresampled($cropped_image, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h, $ow, $oh);
```

But in fact, are you sure you're not looking for a straight copy of the cropped region?

```
imagecopy($cropped_image, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $ow, $oh);
```

Comment: This does not work as expected, because image are resampled. I need a 1:1 image, but crop the part user select.

Comment: I need only a piece of original image, but with same proportion. For instance, a square of 300x300px from a image of 400x400px.

Comment: that's what `imagecopy` will do

Comment: Made some changes here and all worked fine with `imagecopy` instead of `imagecopyresampled`, thanks! (:

Answer (score 0):

because you omitted the quality on imagejpeg() it defaults to 75%
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

can you try adding 95 on 3rd parameter?

```
imagejpeg($cropped_image, 'fileToCrop.jpg', 95);
```

P.S.
If you can use a 3rdparty php script I'll suggest you just use timthumb
http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/

if you need a change of cropping location,

http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/08/timthumb-part-4-moving-crop-location/

Comment: I already have quality defined, but does not work as expected.